# NGINX in docker can't get the real user IP

Tags: docker, nginx

I have only one nginx  in docker's container.
Please help me. I searched Google for this question

I have only one container in which to deploy this nginx PHP normally used as a development environment.
PHP cannot get the real client IP address.
No matter how I set NGINX, it doesn't work

This is nginx config

```
listen 80;
server_name lh.hello.test;

location / {
              proxy_pass http://lh.hello.test;
              proxy_set_header    Host             $host:$server_port;
              proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header    HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
              proxy_redirect      default;
}
```

This is PHP `$_SERVER`

```
    'USER' => string 'hello' (length=6)
    'HOME' => string '/home/hello' (length=12)
    'HTTP_CONNECTION' => string 'keep-alive' (length=10)
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE' => string 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' (length=23)
    'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => string 'gzip, deflate' (length=13)
    'HTTP_ACCEPT' => string 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' (length=85)
    'HTTP_DNT' => string '1' (length=1)
    'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => string 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36' (length=120)
    'HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS' => string '1' (length=1)
    'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL' => string 'max-age=0' (length=9)
    'HTTP_HOST' => string 'lh.hello.test:800' (length=18)
    'SCRIPT_FILENAME' => string '/workspace/myProject/hello_blog/public/index.php' (length=49)
    'REDIRECT_STATUS' => string '200' (length=3)
    'SERVER_NAME' => string 'lh.hello.test' (length=14)
    'SERVER_PORT' => string '80' (length=2)
    'SERVER_ADDR' => string '172.17.0.4' (length=10)
    'REMOTE_PORT' => string '54908' (length=5)
    'REMOTE_ADDR' => string '172.17.0.1' (length=10)
    'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => string 'nginx/1.14.0' (length=12)
    'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => string 'CGI/1.1' (length=7)
    'REQUEST_SCHEME' => string 'http' (length=4)
    'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => string 'HTTP/1.1' (length=8)
    'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => string '/workspace/myProject/hello_blog/public' (length=39)
    'DOCUMENT_URI' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
    'REQUEST_URI' => string '/test/test' (length=10)
    'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
    'CONTENT_LENGTH' => string '' (length=0)
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => string '' (length=0)
    'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'GET' (length=3)
    'QUERY_STRING' => string '/test/test' (length=10)
    'FCGI_ROLE' => string 'RESPONDER' (length=9)
    'PHP_SELF' => string '/index.php' (length=10)
    'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => float 1536761653.4628
    'REQUEST_TIME' => int 1536761653
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using nginx proxy,

first add proxy config

```
  location / {
         # proxy host and ip information
         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

         # proxy 
         proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx;
     }
```

then you can ge real ip by 【X-Real-IP】value in request header.